# LogLogPlot not showing plot over full plot range

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I am attempting to do a simple log-log-plot in Mathematica 12.0:

```
LogLogPlot[10^-11/(10 (t/1000000)^2), {t, 0, 10000}, PlotRange -> {{1, 10000}, {10^-8, 1}}]
```

Despite giving an explicit PlotRange, the plot is only shown for values >10 with a gap below 10 (see image below). I tried increasing PlotPoints, but this did not help.
How can I get Mathematica to also plot the values between 1 and 10?

[image: Mathematica output (plot)]

Comment: You can not make a LogLog plot starting at zero. You must start at an suitable chosen small number.

Comment: @DanielHuber Ugh, thanks! I feel stupid now. Really simple fix, but I would never have figured that one out myself.

Comment: Happens to everybody  :)

Answer (score 1):

The (embarrasingly simple) answer was given by Daniel Huber in the comments:

```
LogLogPlot[10^-11/(10 (t/1000000)^2), {t, 10^-8, 10000}, PlotRange -> {{1, 10000}, {10^-8, 1}}]
```

fixes the problem.